# How to replace current directory with a backup directory?

Tags: 14.04, copy

I have two directories: 'current' and 'backup'. I am using an Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

The task I need to complete from command line is to take the directory 'backup', and replace the 'current' directory with the 'backup' directory.

**Note**: There may be files which exist in the 'current' directory that do not exist in 'backup' directory. These files should be removed when the 'current' directory is replaced by the 'backup' directory.

In effect, I need a way to replace the 'current' directory with the 'backup' directory. How can this be achieved?

Comment: mv current current.old ; cp -R backup current

Comment: rsync -avh backup/ current/ --delete - note this is more destructive then the first command but will potentially take less time.

Answer (score 0):

Non-destructive

```
#Make a backup in "current.old"
mv current current.old

#copy from backup
cp -R backup current
```

Destructive - you will loose files in current and changes since backup will be overwritten

```
rsync -avh backup/ current/ --delete
```